# How can I handle calling a function that returns a promise inside a defer.resolve()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have an AngularJS function that uses $q. In the function I have a call to %http and in the .then functions I return `defer.resolve()` or `defer.reject()`.

However I realized that before the resolve I need to go to a different state which I do with `this.$state.go(..)` which returns a promise.

So I am confused. My code is expecting a defer.resolve() so how do I handle this. Can I just return `this.$state.go(...)`?

```
topicDeleteSubmit = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var self = this;
    var defer = self.$q.defer();
    self.$http({
        url: self.url,
        method: "DELETE"
    })
        .then(
        (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): any => {
                // Original code 
                this.$state.go('home.subjects.subject.admin.topics', {
                    subjectId: this.sus.subject.id
                });
                defer.resolve();

                // New code
                return this.$state.go('home.subjects.subject.admin.topics', {
                    subjectId: this.sus.subject.id
                });
            },
            (error): any => {
                defer.reject(error);
            }
            )
    return defer.promise;
}
```

**Update**

My tests seem to show that I do need to add my own defer in the way of Duncan's answer.  I would welcome comments from others confirming this or proving me wrong.

Comment: get rid of `$q` altogether and just return `$http`. You are using an anti-pattern since `$http` already returns a promise

Comment: @charlietfl - I see what you are saying but how would that work if the "this.$state.go( .... ) (that returns a promise) returned a failed promise because of something happening when the state change didn't work?

Comment: If you just had the call to `$http` I would agree with @charlietfl, but as you are using it yourself to trigger some additional actions I think in this case you want to create your own promise to be resolved when all of your actions are completed.

Comment: but the actual `delete` at server was accomplished so if you fail with `$state.go` what are you going to show user as problem? A statechange error handler would cover it wouldn't it?

Comment: @Anne If $state.go fails, the error will move up the promise chain and make topicDeleteSubmit return that failed promise, similar to an exception travelling through the function stack. Similarly, you can "catch" the error by adding this to $state.go: `.then(null, function() { });`. I'm of the opinion that you should be able to do this method without making a custom `defer`. It takes a bit of understanding of the way `.then` works, but it's good practice.

Comment: @Katana314 - would you mind adding your suggestion as an answer. I think Duncan is suggesting it still needs to be another promise so I'd like to get another opinion. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll preface my answer with a caveat. I don't have a lot of knowledge of angularjs, but I do know promises pretty well.

```
topicDeleteSubmit = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    // Not bothering with 'self'; properly-compiled arrow functions () => should
    // inherit `this`.
    return this.$http({
        url: this.url,
        method: "DELETE"
    })
        .then(
        (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<any>): any => {
                return this.$state.go('home.subjects.subject.admin.topics', {
                    subjectId: this.sus.subject.id
                });
            }
            // by not including an error handler, the method that calls this one
            // will need to resolve any errors. Any low-level errors will copy
            // over to the promise that expects their result. (similar to
            // exception handling)
            );
}
```

Comment: I tried this by putting in a state that was not valid.  topicDeleteSubmit return a success. I really do think I will need to add the $q as Duncan has suggested.  I'd also welcome opinions from others.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the promise returned by `$state.go()` resolves before resolving the original promise:

```
            this.$state.go('home.subjects.subject.admin.topics', {
                subjectId: this.sus.subject.id
            }).then(function() {
                defer.resolve();
            });
```

Comment: Couple of questions. I had originally had a return before "this.$state.go...    reading your answer, can I assume this was the wrong way to do it?  Also can I assume that to make it 100% valid I would also need a defer.reject in the .then( ...    Thanks

Comment: The `defer.reject` call that you have is probably fine. You might add another reject call in case `$state.go` can fail but if it isn't likely to fail that might not be needed. I doubt the `return` you had was needed as the promise returned by `$http` isn't going to care what if anything you return.

Comment: charlietfl was mentioning this was an anti-pattern but as the state.go returns a promise this was the only way i could think to do it. Do you see any other way. Thanks